# convert path into absolute url

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I have a part of URL like below:

```
"employee/employeeDetail.aspx"
```

And the base path of the whole URL is:

```
"example.com/siteName"
```

And the desired output should be:

```
"http://www.example.com/siteName/employee/employeeDetail.aspx"
```

I've tried the below:

```
page.ResolveClientUrl(@"/employee/employeeDetail.aspx");
```

But the result was

```
"/employee/employeeDetail.aspx"
```

Instead of combining the two strings i.e.

```
string baseURL = @"example.com/siteName";
string relativeURL = @"employee/employeeDetail.aspx";
string finalURL = baseURL + relativeURL;
```

Are there any other better ways to form a URL?

---

I've tried adding `~` before the baseURL

```
page.ResolveClientUrl(@"~/employee/employeeDetail.aspx");
```

But the outcome was

```
../employee/employeeDetail.aspx
```

Comment: Have you looked into the [UriBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class?

Comment: @tjleigh: No need to. This is suitable for this situation. UriBuilder would be overkill.

Comment: Probably. It is a robust way of coping with missing/extraneous slashes though. (OP's code as it is would set finalURL to `example.com/siteNameemployee/employeeDetail.aspx`)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, it's best to take a look at the incoming request and to build from that...

```
var ub = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
var someNewPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/app/relative/path");
ub.Path = someNewPath;
ub.Query = perhapsAQueryString;
var absoluteUri = ub.Uri;
```

...but sometimes when you're behind a load-balancer, things might get more complicated, and you have to look at headers added by the load-balancer, such as `X-REQUESTED-FOR`

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the method that your url is relative from the application root path by adding the `~` at the beginning:

```
page.ResolveClientUrl(@"~/employee/employeeDetail.aspx");
```

If you don't do that, it will be resolved as absolute path from the root of your webserver.

Answer (score 1):

you missed  `'~'` symbol

tilde (~) to indicate the root.

```
page.ResolveClientUrl(@"~/employee/employeeDetail.aspx");
```